# Does it matter if I reuse a variable after running a function with the same variable?

Tags: php

As the title states, does it matter - will it make any difference?

Example:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
```

Can this cause any problems or is this fine? I've seen a lot of examples, where they create new variables:

Example:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$escaped_username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not cause any problems.  The cases where new variables are used are usually either to make easier to follow code, or because the original variable is still needed later on in the code block.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a third example:

```
$usernameRequest = $_POST['username'];

... 

$usernameMySQLEscapeString = mysql_real_escape_string($usernameRequest);

...
```

The more information you put into the name of the variable, the more it tells you. Train your ability to find good names and you will write good code.

Comment: +1, but I would argue that `$usernameMySQLEscapeString` is not a good variable name.  It's unnecessarily verbose.  Something like `$usernameClean` or `$usernameEscaped` would be much better, IMHO.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: You are totally right, it's not a good name. It's sort of a bad example to make a point. *Escape* and *Clean* might be better, but names most often depend on the context we're reading them, so I leave this to the imagination of the TS to find a fitting one for his/her code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, you can even further improve it:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```